# Большой размер apk

Tags: android, android-library

У меня сделан проект на базе библиотеки XWalkView.

В моём случае она прогружает определённый сайт, но проблема в том,что данная библиотека очень много весит. Загрузочный apk весит под 45mb, хотя по сути там ничего нету.

Я читал на форумах,что данный apk можно как-то разбить на две части: одна для ARM, вторая для x86, что-то такое, одним словом для разных платформ. После можно как-то это всё загрузить в PlayMarket и уже когда пользователь захотел скачать данную программу Play Market сам выбирает определённый apk для его платформы.

Собственно вопрос: как распарсить apk на две части и как собственно их залить в Play Market так,чтобы Play Market сам выбирал какой ему apk нужен?

Comment: Я не особо в теме, что это за `XWalkView`, но чтобы уменьшить размер apk способом, которым вы хотите, у вас в проекте должны быть неуниверсальные ресурсы. К примеру, изображения для разных разрешений экрана, либо бинарники под разные платформы. Тогда можно будет разделить это в разные `apk` для разных платформ. Но подумайте, а если кто-то захочет скинуть приложение другу через какой-нибудь `shareit`? И оно там не запустится или будут какие-то косяки. Я бы не стал так делать, а постарался бы **выпилить все ненужное из проекта**. Вы просто, кажется, не в том месте пытаетесь оптимизировать вес.

Comment: @selya если убрать эту библиотеку,размер сразу же упадёт до 2-5мб

Comment: Если я правильно понял, это что-то типо веб-окружения. Crosswalk project типо? гляньте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk). 1 минута поиска в гугле. Там объясняют, что данная библа сильно увеличивает размер апк. А еще есть `lite`-версия. И что-то про компиляцию еще. Может будет полезно

Comment: Новые приложения нельзя заливать в Google Play в формате APK. Теперь новый формат AAB, и этот формат и так все сам должен разбивать под разные архитектуры. Пользователь будет скачивать приложение только под свою архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play действительно сам подбирает нужную платформу и разрешение для устройства, вот только для этого не используется APK формат. Необходимо собрать и подписать приложение в AAB формате, это своего рода пакет файлов вашего приложения который в последствии обрабатывается в Google.

Answer (score -2):

Да так можно, вот [подробная статья](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html) как это делать, я правда так не делал никогда. 
Но 45M не сильно большой размер, я бы не делал так ради красоты только - ну и что что 45M? Это же не 45G, у многих дома 100Mb/s канал давно уже, даже в провинциях.

Альтернативное рациональное предложение - взять исходники [XWalkWiew](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk), убрать оттуда все что вам не нужно, установить в проект и собрать...

Comment: Максимальный размер apk — 100МБ, так что я бы не советовал так легко разбрасываться мегабайтами

Comment: А вообще ответы-ссылки не приветствуются на Stack Overflow

Comment: 100 Mb - 45 Mb = 55 Mb - кто чем разбрасывается?? и как ответить на такой вопрос кроме как ссылкой?

Comment: @EugeneBartosh мне мама в детстве говорила, что копейка рубль бережет. А ответ должен быть (как я считаю) хоть сколько-нибудь развернутым, дабы из него было понятно, то ли это, что хотел человек.

Comment: @andreymal меня тоже мама научила хорошим вещам, и экономности в том числе :-) но есть просто соображения целесообразности, в конце концов удобства, экономии собственного труда и так далее - если приложение вырастет до 80Mb - стоит задуматься, но у меня есть приложения по 80Mb+, увеличение не предполагается - и не сказал бы что мне из-за этого не спится )

Comment: @andreymal я разрабатываю для Android на Unity 3D и мне нужны к этому библиотеки типа OpenCV, DLIB и пр - все приложения примерно такими и получаются, около 80M

Comment: @EugeneBartosh а у меня свободного места на телефоне всего ~200МБ. Из-за этого самые большие приложения я периодически просто удаляю независимо от их полезности ;)

Comment: @andreymal а я вот почти так же делаю. Только еще перед скачиванием) Если приложение большое, а функционала в нем вроде как-то и нет, то просто не устанавливаю. Если разработчик не мог сделать нормальным размер, то как он мог сделать нормальное приложение в целом?)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/224172)

Comment: Возможно, найдете полезные моменты для себя в этой [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339938/).

Comment: @alexander barakin ну ссылка как бэ на Android Dev manual от Google - если ссылка пропадёт то и ответ на вопрос, и даже рискну предположить что и сам вопрос станут неактуальны :-)